# Multiple media queries running at the same time for different page elements

Tags: css, media-queries

I have something weird happening in my media queries, different media queries are being applied at the same time on different page elements.
I have no idea why and not even sure what code I should show for this.  My media queries are stacked properly

Here are two of my media queries, one of the elements in question is ImagePath, 913px is overridng the 969px. When I inspect treelist and TreeSelectItems the 969px media query is running

```
@media (max-height: 969px) {
    #tabPanelAccAttMod {
        display: none;
    }
    #txtSearch {
        width: 137px !important;
    }

    #tabPanelItemAcc {
        height: 803px !important;
        /*height: calc(100vh - 166px) !important;*/
    }

    #tabPanelAccAttMod {
        height: 781px !important;
    }

    #AttachmentsGrid {
        height: 391px !important;
    }

    #AttachMods {
        width: 310px !important;
    }

    #divSplitterButtons.shift {
        right: 310px !important;
    }

    #ImagePathAttach {
        height: 253px !important;
    }

    #ImagePath {
        height: 149px !important;
    }

    #treelist {
        height: 200px !important;
    }

    #TreeSelectItems {
        height: 215px !important;
    }

    #AttachmentsGrid {
        height: 438px !important;
    }
}

@media (max-height: 913px) {
    #AttachMods {
        width: 275px !important;
    }

    #BigImage{
        width:675px !important;
    }
    #tabPanelItemAcc {
        height: 752px !important;
    }

    #ImagePath {
        height: 205px !important;
    }

    #AttachmentsGrid {
        height: 412px !important;
    }

    #BigImage.show-big-image {
        right: 273px !important;
        transition: 0.5s !important;
    }

    #ImageListViewWrapper.show-image-list {
        right: 273px !important;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }

    #txtSearch {
        width: 212px !important;
    }

    #txtAttchSearch {
        width: 212px !important;
    }
}

@media (max-height: 906px) {
    #AttachMods {
        width: 200px !important;
    }

    #BigImage.show-big-image {
        right: 198px !important;
        transition: 0.5s !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ZohirSalak, I guess you missed the part where i mentioned that I am not sure what code to show for this

Comment: Question about media queries obviously Show the media queries that you think are stacked properly because someone else might see something you're not seeing.

Comment: @ZohirSalak, Thank you. I will do that now

Comment: You'll have to put up a code snippet illustrating the issue, Also is using `max-height` for the media intended ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak, Yes the max-height is intended. The widths are working fine. I have to use heights because its a web application using kendo ui framework and not a website. There are a multitude of different elements, and using kendo splitters as well. So across 4k resolutions and everything else, the heights were a major problem

Comment: I ran the code and it works as expected from height 914px it applies styles from `@media (max-height: 969px)`

Comment: @ZohirSalak, so that tells me that the queries are stacked properly then. So I am going to have to dig deeper in the code. The other reason using heights is if a user has their bookmarks bar open

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
@media (max-height: 969px) and (min-height: 913px) {
    #tabPanelAccAttMod {
        display: none;
    }
    #txtSearch {
        width: 137px !important;
    }

    #tabPanelItemAcc {
        height: 803px !important;
        /*height: calc(100vh - 166px) !important;*/
    }

    #tabPanelAccAttMod {
        height: 781px !important;
    }

    #AttachmentsGrid {
        height: 391px !important;
    }

    #AttachMods {
        width: 310px !important;
    }

    #divSplitterButtons.shift {
        right: 310px !important;
    }

    #ImagePathAttach {
        height: 253px !important;
    }

    #ImagePath {
        height: 149px !important;
    }

    #treelist {
        height: 200px !important;
    }

    #TreeSelectItems {
        height: 215px !important;
    }

    #AttachmentsGrid {
        height: 438px !important;
    }
}

@media (max-height: 913px) and (min-height: 906px) {
    #AttachMods {
        width: 275px !important;
    }

    #BigImage{
        width:675px !important;
    }
    #tabPanelItemAcc {
        height: 752px !important;
    }

    #ImagePath {
        height: 205px !important;
    }

    #AttachmentsGrid {
        height: 412px !important;
    }

    #BigImage.show-big-image {
        right: 273px !important;
        transition: 0.5s !important;
    }

    #ImageListViewWrapper.show-image-list {
        right: 273px !important;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }

    #txtSearch {
        width: 212px !important;
    }

    #txtAttchSearch {
        width: 212px !important;
    }
}

@media (max-height: 906px) {
    #AttachMods {
        width: 200px !important;
    }

    #BigImage.show-big-image {
        right: 198px !important;
        transition: 0.5s !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem with your media queries explained below :

```
@media screen and (max-height: 969px) and (min-height: 913px) {
    // your styles
}

@media screen and (max-height: 913px) and (min-height: 906px) {
    // your styles
}

@media screen and (max-height: 906) {
    // your styles
}
```

Comment: Have to use max-height because the widths aren't the problem

Comment: My bad, I've fixed the code. You can test it now I think it'll fix the problem